# android - help on gps location

Tags: android, gps

In my android program I set the minimum time and minimum distance when requesting for the gps. However only sometimes the 'onLocationChanged' action occurs when I start listening.

If I stop listening and then start listening, does it compare the values of the new gps with the gps value from the past? Do I need to clear it somehow when I start listening?

Note: i am in the same location when testing.

Comment: By start and stop do you mean LocationManager's requestLocationUpdates() and removeUpdates()? Each time I call requestLocationUpdates() regardless of the previous location's minimum time and distance my phone searches for a new fix. onLocationChanged() is only called after a fix is calculated, if I have poor line of sight to the sky this can take awhile, if it ever happens.

Answer (score 0):

use getLastKnownLocation for using last known location.

Comment: what i am asking is, why the onLocationChanged function occurs sometimes.

Comment: onLocationChanged called only when you set some minimum distance changed from previous location. or you can also set some time has been passed

Comment: Well, why LocationChanged fnction called sometimes, for that you should paste your code and listener for it.

Answer (score 0):

Take this as an example:

```
LocationManager loc = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(
    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE
);
loc.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener
);
```

The `onLocationChanged()`-method of the handling `LocationListener` will be called when:

- You moved *at least* 10 meters since the last update
- At least 2 seconds have *passed* since the last update

The documentation of the [`requestLocationUpdates()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) gives some more information:

> [...] **The elapsed time between location updates will never be *less*
>   than `minTime`**, although it can be more depending on the Location
>   Provider implementation and the update interval requested by other
>   applications.
>
> [...] The `minDistance` parameter can also be used to control the
>   frequency of location updates. **If it is greater than 0 then the
>   location provider will only send your application an update when the
>   location has changed by *at least* `minDistance` meters, AND *at least*
>   `minTime` milliseconds have passed.**

Also, it contains the following information:

> **Prior to Jellybean, the minTime parameter was only a hint**, and some
>   location provider implementations ignored it. **From Jellybean and
>   onwards it is mandatory for Android compatible devices to observe both
>   the minTime and minDistance parameters.**

This is just a mechanism to save some battery, you don't have to do anything yourself, other then choose an appropriate value for both those parameters.